# requiring unknown module "519" ReactNative

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

### Error info

> requiring unknown module "519", if you are sure the module exists, try
>   restarting Metro. You may also want to run 'yarn' or 'npm install'

I just add ant-design in my rn program and run pod install and restart android app.

No error in my iOS Application, but wrong with Android application.

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with npm install? Usually the error means that you don't have installed a plugin or that you are importing something in the wrong mode.